# How to find items in sequence and group them?

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have the following:

```
public class Person
{
public string Name{get;set;}
public string Other{get;set;}
public string Other2{get;set;}
public int? Sequence{get;set;}
}
```

---

```
new Person("bob","other1","other2",1)
new Person("bob","other1","other2",2)
new Person("bob","other1","other2",3)
new Person("bob","other1","other2",4)
new Person("Alice","other1","other2")
new Person("Alice","other1","other2",1)
new Person("Alan","other1","other2",1)
new Person("Alan","other1","other2",2)
new Person("Alan","other1","other2",3)
new Person("Alex","other1","other2")
new Person("Alex","other1","other2",1)
new Person("Alex","other1","other2",2)
```

As shown some of the objects have sequence 1-n and some don't.

Could I use LINQ to pull objects by sequence from the given list?

Desired output would be:
Bob and all his related data where a sequence is there like 1,2,3,4 records
Alex 2 records as he only has sequences 1 and 2.

So the output would be another object by name and data by sequence.

```
new {Name="Bob", Data=new[]{
Other = "other"
Sequence = 1
Other2 = "Other2" //etc
}}
```

The sequence will always increment by 1 and be in order, but how many there might be is unknown.

If I have not made something clear just ask.

**What I tried**
I tried without using LINQ and looping through the list and processing each object and passing out a newly created object for each row using lots of if's.

I am just wondering if there is an easier way with LINQ although my way works it's ugly.

Comment: `.Where(x => x.Sequence.HasValue)`?

Comment: If you show what you tried it's clear to us where you need help *specifically*.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay appreciate the response but that would not give the desired object output where each name is tied to data in sequence as per my update.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly:

```
var result = yourCollection
    .Where(x => x.Sequence.HasValue)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(grp => new
    {
        Name = grp.Key,
        Data = grp.Select(x => new
        {
            x.Other,
            x.Sequence,
            x.Other2
        })
    });
```

This assumes the list is already ordered by `Sequence`; if not, just add an `.OrderBy(x => x.Sequence.Value)` before the `GroupBy`.

Comment: HasValue might always return true as sequence can go 1,2,3,4 and then 1,2 and then just 1.  So will this take that into account?

Comment: `HasValue` will return false for any null `Sequence`. Any with a value (1, 2, 3, 4 etc.) will return true.

Comment: As per my first comment maybe it was not clear.  HasValue will return true if the sequence column is full.  My question as was will Name be tied to its own sequences, for example Bob has 1,2,3,4 but can appear next with Bob 1 and then Bob 1,2 so will this create 3 Objects for Bob? Because the Sequence resets.

Comment: `Where` is placed before `GroupBy`, so it is working with your original list. It is simply preventing any `Person` objects with a null `Sequence` from entering the `GroupBy`, which is a requirement I deduced from your question.

Comment: Ok I will test this and see the result.